# How to insert several of the same image in a html table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a memory card game, and it is required to be in a table. So to start, I need several of the same image (the back of a playing card). I have the image inserted already and it loads as it should, here is the code so far:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="default.asp">
        <img src="back.gif" alt="Please re-load" style="width:200px;height:249px;border:0;">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is also required that instead of hard coding it, I use a for loop to call the image several times. I know this is probably very easy to do but I am a beginner and have been trying this for a few hours now.

Comment: What did you try? Please show us some code... we can't guess where your problem is.

Comment: You mean using javascript? Is jQuery allowed? Or do you mean a for loop with haml?

Comment: Do you want to use Jquery, Angular or plain old JS?

Comment: You can use `CSS` to change the image source for all at single line of code.

Comment: Yes, using javascript. Sorry, I should have clarified.

Comment: @Robo Does you problem solved?

Comment: I added an answer to your issue. Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can create elements using plain javascript in a for loop. HTML side, you just need an empty table to append elements to.

```js
var width = 4;
var height = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
  for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "http://www.bgdf.com/sites/default/files/images/AAAADEnelREAAAAAAM6-JASMALL.preview.jpg");

    a.appendChild(img);
    td.appendChild(a);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  document.getElementById("memoryGame").appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
#memoryGame img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id="memoryGame">
</table>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id="box"` to contener in which you want to store your images.

```
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += '<img src="back.gif" alt="Please re-load" style="width:200px;height:249px;border:0;">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/h6uwpjt1/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $('#table1 tr').append('<td><a href="default.asp"><img src="back.gif" alt="Please re-load" style="width:200px;height:249px;border:0;"></a></td>')
    }
```

Of course it depends on how many imgs you want in each row, but then you can change the code. Let's say you want only 3 imgs in each row, then just say

```
if((i % 3) == 0)
{
   //Append a </tr> to close the existing tr.
   //Append a new <tr> to begin the new row.
}
```